# Number of Elements of order 4 in $S_6$

Tags: group-theory

Number of Elements of order 4 in $S_6$?

My attempt:
So we need Permutations of the form -

(a b c d) 
Which equal 
$\frac{6!}{4.2!} $

And

(a b c d)(e f)
Which equal

$\frac{6!}{4.2!}\frac{2!}{2.2}$

Total we add them.

$\frac{6!}{4.2!} +  \frac{6!}{4.2!}\frac{2!}{2.2}$
?
Whats wrong? Answer should be 180 as per book

Comment: $\frac{2!}{2\cdot 2}$ should just be 1, not $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @vadim123  Extra 2 in denomenator is to eliminate repitition of (a b c d)(e f) and (e f)(a b c d) , which are same.

Comment: User786, why would you want to divide by two. In your tally you did not include elements of type $(e f)(a b c d)$ at all. Correctly, because those are the same elements. Because the cycles are of different lengths (4 and 2), no overcounting takes place. The situation is markedly different from a tally of permutations that are product of two disjoint cycles of an equal length.

Answer (score 3):

As you noted, there are $6!/(4\cdot 2!)$ distinct 4-cycles. For each 4-cycle, there are two possibilities for the remaining elements: either
$$(a\ b\ c\ d)(e)(f)$$
or
$$(a\ b\ c\ d)(e\ f)$$
So the total number of elements of order 4 is 
$$2 \cdot \frac{6!}{4\cdot 2!} = \frac{6!}{4}$$

Comment: Isn't (a b c d) case equivalent to (a b c d)(e)(f) case?

Comment: It's the same case.